# JBoss7/WildFly webapp - how to access properties file from class

Tags: java, file, properties, jboss, wildfly

I try to load webapp project's settings from own `config.properties` file, but there's no success: the file not found. I can't use `ServletContext` method, because i've access the file from **ordinary class**.

```
file = Config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
```

- it's returns null.

I've tried to put the file to `WEB-INF` and `resources` folders, still doesn't work :(

Any ideas how to force this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting files in WEB-INF/classes .

If you put your config in src, than after compile it will be in WEB-INF/classes.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation for configuration files that would solve your problem is to place them in a folder that depends on an environment variable.

If you application is called **MyApp**, then you can force the user to place that file in the folder that points the environment variable **MY_APP**. You could in fact make it mandatory to run the application with a start up check.

Usually you should specify default values for your configuration parameters if you want your application to run without the environment variable.

To get enviroment variables in Java you can use [System.getenv();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html)